# cannot import name linkedin

Tags: python, linkedin-api

### I am here for the first time like a member and I'm new in python. I want to get a API string from linkedin using 'python-linkedin' package like this:

```
from linkedin import linkedin

API_KEY = 'my_key'
API_SECRET = 'my_secret'
RETURN_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
print authentication.authorization_url  # open this url on your browser
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
```

**I have got this error:**

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/alemcluster.ALEM/PycharmProjects/linkedinapi/linkedin.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/alemcluster.ALEM/PycharmProjects/linkedinapi/linkedin.py", line 1, in <module>
from linkedin import linkedin
  File "C:\Users\alemcluster.ALEM\PycharmProjects\linkedinapi\linkedin.py", line 1, in <module>
from linkedin import linkedin
ImportError: cannot import name linkedin

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**I tried to change linkedin to another variable, but does not help. I'm sorry if it is not properly posted. Prior to this, I only looked answers to questions.**

Comment: Your filename `linkedin.py` shadows correct package. Python looks up your working dir first, and `linkedin.py` looks like something it should impost from, since name matches. Rename it to any other name and code should work just fine.

Comment: Btw. Does anyone know if there is any canonical duplicate for these kind of questions?

Comment: Sorry, you mean, I have to go to the directory where my 'python-linkedin' package stored and rename it to 'linkedin.py'?

Comment: Try `import linkedin` rather than `from linkedin import linkedin`

Comment: No, I mean _file you're actually run_. `C:\Users\alemcluster.ALEM\PycharmProjects\linkedinapi\linkedin.py`. Rename it to e.g. `my_app.py`.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, it works)

Comment: Do you know another ways to get access to companies information in the LinkedIn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got similar issue a while back. This is due to because your filename is also same as your library name and python interpreter first looks library in a working directory. And when interpreter checks working directory interpreter founds a same name as library name so interpreter start getting from it which is actually not library. That's why it is giving error.

**Simple rename your file and you are good to go.**

Hope It Works :)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.
Initially I used 
pip3 install python-linkedin
When I googled this issue, I saw that it works only for python2 but

I later tried
`pip3 install python3-linkedin`

Now import statement works fine for me. Restart IDE and try...
Hope that helps

---

If you installed `linkedin`, and/or `python3-linkedin`, you will want to first uninstall **both** packages and re-install `python3-linkedin` afterwards to ensure things work.

Comment: I saw some weird behavior after I already removed the old package, updated answer to remove both packages to start clean before installing the newer one.